# What happened to Babylon 4 after the war between Shadows and Minbari ended a thousand years ago?

Tags: babylon-5

The *Babylon 5* episode, "[War Without End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Without_End_(Babylon_5))", shows that the Babylon 4 station was sent back in time 1000 years to help the Minbari in the war against the Shadows.

What happened to the B-4 station after that war?

I will accept answers from novelizations as well as TV episode scripts or movie scripts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was explained in the Babylon 5 comic book limited series "In Valen's Name", written by JMS (and Peter David) so definitely canon.

> Delenn reveals that after the last Shadow War, Babylon 4 was taken to a place of rest, its final location a secret. The crew who took it there never returned. Its fate was a mystery for nine hundred years -- until now.
>
> http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/comic/012.html

I can't find my copy of the series but here's what a [B5 fan wiki](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Babylon_4) says about the conclusion:

> For over 900 years the station lay dormant, guarded by the Tak'cha, who referred to it as Ende X'Ton ("the lost station") which they believed to be a holy place. In 2261 it was found floating adrift in Sector 730 by 12 by 9 by John Sheridan, Delenn, Michael Garibaldi, and Susan Ivanova. Within 48 hours of rediscovering the station, Babylon 4 burned up in the atmosphere of the planet it was orbiting.

Comment: It survives for almost a thousand years, then gets destroyed within 48 hours of them finding it? Typical.